# In python how to store the values of loop in a python?

Tags: python

I tried to append these values in the list but it appends only else part.

I want to store these values i printed in a list. How can i achieve this??

```
for i in d["Cabin new"]:
    if i=="nan":
        print ("na")
    else:
        print (i[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append in both places:

```
res = []
for i in d["Cabin new"]:
    if i=="nan":
        res.append('na')
    else:
        res.append(i[1:])
```